# Produces Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been learning about Web API recently, and making plans to increase the scalability of my MVC apps, using it. When I finally got into creating a Web API controller, though, I discovered a `[Produces("application/json")]` annotation applied to the controller class. I haven't been able to figure out what that annotation does. I want the controller to only accept json input, so is this tag helpful to me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ProducesAnnotation only matters the response formatting. So this is not helpful for your need to restrict your input.

You can direct the content negotiation process to a specific type for the output of controller actions or a specific action by using  ProducesAnnotation from the ASP.NET Core MVC framework.
From the documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/formatting.html):

> If you would like to restrict the response formats for a specific
>   action you can, you can apply the [Produces] filter.

If you want to restrict inputs to json on a global level you could configure MVC on startup to have only a single InputFormatter of type JsonInputFormatter in your Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...    
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        // Add XML Content Negotiation
        config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        config.InputFormatters.Clear();
        config.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonInputFormatter());
    });
    ...
}
```

On Controller or Action level the counterpart of [Produces] is the [Consumes] Annotation. With

```
[Consumes("application/json")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] CallModel model)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

calls to this controller will only succeed if the client provides Content-Type header of application/json. Otherwise a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) will be returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it be possible to apply that configuration to just one controller?

Comment: I have added the new information about the ConsumesAttribute - I hope this fulfills your requirement.

Comment: It should. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Produces attribute restricts the response to only the types defined.  You can add more than one by using the attribute this way.

`[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]`

ASP.NET Core uses a default value of JSON.   If you want xml as well you will also have to specify the xml formatter in the ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()));
```

Comment: Do you know if its possible to define a type for each of the content types?

For example, i have a situation where i need to support application/json and application/geo+json. 

My controller handles the content negotiation based on the accept header. But as it seems you can only have one produces annotation for each controller method.